# Passing servlet response to servlet request without client -- needed for Java SSO (Single-Sign-On) authentication

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, response

Note: This question is specifically for Java but I suppose it can apply to nearly any server-side language.

I have a login page with a form that submits to an application's servlet for authentication.  I had to modify the login to submit to the an SSO servlet for authentication.  However, I need to pass back the SSO servlet response to the application's servlet so it can complete its part.  I don't want the SSO servlet to return back to the client; I want it to pass the baton to the application's servlet, which will do its thing and return a response back to the client.

How can I realize this approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the SSO servlet you can issue a redirect to the browser with the necessary parameters. Redirect URL should be your application's servlet. Refer

[http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)